# Reading CSV using spark-csv package in spark-shell

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-csv

I am trying to use [spark-csv](https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv) to read a csv from aws s3 in spark-shell.

Below are the steps that I did. Started spark-shell using below command

> bin/spark-shell --packages com.databricks:spark-csv_2.10:1.2.0

In the shell, executed the following scala code

```
scala> val hadoopConf = sc.hadoopConfiguration
scala> hadoopConf.set("fs.s3.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.NativeS3FileSystem")
scala> hadoopConf.set("fs.s3.awsAccessKeyId", "****")
scala> hadoopConf.set("fs.s3.awsSecretAccessKey", "****")

scala> val s3path = "s3n://bucket/sample.csv"
scala> val df = sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", "true").load(s3path)
```

Getting the below error

```
java.io.IOException: No FileSystem for scheme: s3n
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getFileSystemClass(FileSystem.java:2584)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2591)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:91)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2630)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2612)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:370)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:296)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.singleThreadedListStatus(FileInputFormat.java:256)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.listStatus(FileInputFormat.java:228)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:313)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.getPartitions(HadoopRDD.scala:207)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:219)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:217)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
```

What is that I am missing here? Please note that I am able to read the csv using

```
scala> sc.textFile(s3path)
```

The same scala code is working fine in [databricks notebook](https://databricks.com/product/databricks) as well

Created a [issue](https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv/issues/137) in spark-csv github. I'll update here when I get answer for the [issue](https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv/issues/137)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the URL `s3n://bucket/sample.csv`, all properties for s3n has to be set. So setting the below properties makes me to read the CSV using spark-csv

```
scala> val hadoopConf = sc.hadoopConfiguration
scala> hadoopConf.set("fs.s3n.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.NativeS3FileSystem")
scala> hadoopConf.set("fs.s3n.awsAccessKeyId", "****")
scala> hadoopConf.set("fs.s3n.awsSecretAccessKey", "****")
```

Refer https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv/issues/137